# Row sum of inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let's say I have a matrix A,
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}& a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
a_{21}& a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
a_{31}& a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
All the elements of A are positive. Now I want to know if there are any properties of this $3\times3$ matrix necessary for the row sums (given by the sum of a particular row's entries) of the inverse of this matrix are always positive.

I tried to take increasing values in the columns, i.e. $a_{11} > a_{21} > a_{31}$, and similarly for all the columns but it depends majorly on the magnitude. So for different magnitude it came out to be different. I also tried for decreasing values but did not reach anywhere. So I thought maybe there is some kind of other property (preferably with some physical significance like values are increasing or something like this) which will result in positive entries of the matrix.

Comment: Show us what you have tried..

Comment: @Qwerty Please take a look at the question again. I tried to add some detail about my approach.

Answer (score 2):

$\boxed{\text{HINT}}$

Let $$\sum_k A_{ik}B_{kj}=\delta_{ij}$$

($B$ is the inverse of $A$). We have:
$$\sum_k A_{ik}\sum_jB_{kj}=\sum_k\sum_jA_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_j\delta_{ij}=1$$

Now you have a relation between the row sum of the matrix and that of the inverse.

Comment: You mentioned two condition in your hint of i=j and i != j, but we have summation over j also. So both condition will come in the equation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @arman I rolled back,,,

Comment: Actually I think it should be 3 because value of $\delta_{ij}$ is one, right??

Comment: @arman it's one only once, the other elements in the row are zero.

Comment: oops!! Right. I misunderstood it.