# How to prove this matrix is an M-matrix or inverse-non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have three matrices $A, B$ and $C$. Matrix $A$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ where $1 >a_i > 0 \forall i$. Matrix $B$ is equal to $(I - D)^{-1}$, where $D$ is non-negative element-wise and has row sums smaller than or equal to 1. Matrix $C$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$, where $c_i \leq 1 - \sum_{j}d_{ij}$. In other words, the diagonal elements of $C$ is smaller than or equal to  1 minus the row sums of $D$.

I want to show that $I - A-(BC)(I-(1+k)A)$ is inverse non-negative, where $k$ is a small positive constant. My initial idea is to show $I - A-(BC)(I-(1+k)A)$ is an M-matrix.

$(I - D)$ is a diagonally dominant Z-matrix, which implies it is also an M-matrix and $B$ is non-negative. This makes $I - A-(BC)(I-(1+k)A)$ a Z-matrix, since its off-diagonals are smaller than or equal to $0$.

We then need to show that $I - A-(BC)(I-(1+k)A)$ is diagonally dominant, or equivalently, the row sums of $A+(BC)(I-(1+k)A)$ is bounded by 1.

By construction of $B$ and $C$, we can show that $BC$ has row sums smaller than or equal to 1 by logic similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868245/row-sum-of-inverse-of-a-matrix).

Let $x_{ij}$ denote the $(i, j)$-th element of the matrix $BC$, row diagonal dominance requires that for each row $i$,
$$1 - a_i -  x_{ii}\left(1 - a_i\left(1+k\right)\right) \geq \sum_{j\neq i} x_{ij} \left(1 - a_j\left(1 + k\right)\right)$$
which I don't think is generally true.

What additional assumption do I need to be able to prove this? In particular, I can add restrictions on the magnitudes/bounds of $a_i$'s or $c_i$'s.

Alternatively, can I prove this instead by showing the matrix is monotone? Any other methods I should try?