# Sum of Rows of Vandermonde Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, proof-writing

**Question** 
Consider some Vandermonde matrix defined by
$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 &x_1^2& ... & x_1^{M-1}\\
1 & x_2 &x_2^2& ... & x_2^{M-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots && \vdots\\
1 & x_M &x_M^2& ... & x_M^{M-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $\{x_i :i = 1, 2, ..., M \land x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Numerically, I have observed that the sum of the rows of the inverse may have an interesting property:
$$
\sum_k (V^{-1})_{i,k} = \delta_{i,0}.
$$
That is, this sum is equal to one for the first row of $V^{-1}$ and zero for all others.

*Is there any way for me to demonstrate this property?*

**Attempts**

1. I began with [elementwise analytical expressions for the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix](http://www.vesnik.math.rs/vol/mv19303.pdf) but was unable to simplify my expressions.
2. Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1868250/1051064), I used expressions for the [sums of a truncated geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) and obtained the expression:
   $$
   \sum_k V^{-1}_{i,k}\left(\frac{1 - x_k^M}{1-x_k} \right) = 1
   $$
   But am unable to see a way forward.
3. Finally, I have found [one proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Elements_of_Inverse_of_Matrix_with_Column_of_Ones) which is necessary for $\sum_k (V^{-1})_{i,k} = \delta_{i,0}$ but certainly not sufficient.

Comment: On a related note, you can represent the coefficients of Fahlhaber's Polynomials as a matrix. The inverse of that matrix is a truncated version of Binomial Coefficients turned into a matrix. chttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By direct calculation, one has
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = V \times \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So multiplying on the left by $V^{-1}$, one gets
$$  V^{-1} \times \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

This means exactly that the sum of the coefficients of the first row of $V^{-1}$ is $1$, and the sums of the other rows are $0$.

Comment: Wow, very nice here! Simple and avoids any of those complex expressions for elementwise values of the inverse. Impressive!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @SeanBrooks You are welcome !

Comment: I think we can conclude this property holds for any invertible matrix with the first column of all ones, which many matrices could have, not just the Vandermonde.

Comment: @whoisit Yes, obviously the given proof works for all such matrices.